# Supnorm on uniformly continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

While I am studying Evans book He define Supnorm on $C(\bar{U})$ is

$$||f||_{C(\bar{U})}:=\sup_{x\in U} |f(x)|.$$

where $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous

and $C(\bar{U})=\{f\in C(U) $ f is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $U$ }

and $C(U)=\{f:U\to \mathbb{R}/u$ continuous $\}$

thank you..advance

my question why define on $C(\bar{U}$ why can't we define on $C(U)$

Answer (score 1):

$C(U)$ consists of just continuous functions.Functions in $C(U)$ need not be bounded so the sup norm may not be finite. For example, if $U=(0,1)$ then $\frac 1 x$ is continuous but $\sup \{|\frac 1 x:x\in U|\}=\infty$.

Comment: …..thanku sir..so important think is every continuous function is need not to be bounded.. right?

Comment: @learner On a compact space all continuous functions are bounded and we can define the sup norm on it. On other topological space we can restrict our attention to bounded continuous functions and sup norm can be defined for these.